# Simulating enter key in Command Prompt is not working

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd /K cd /d D:\Path\&abcd.bat"
wait 5
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

The line

```
WshShell.Run "cmd /K cd /d D:\Path\&abcd.bat"
```

is working fine, runs the abcd.bat file (runs the file, then command prompt asks to press the enter key), but pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

is not working. QTP/UFT is not doing anything and skips this line of code and moves to next line.

I tried

```
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WshShell.SendKeys "(Chr(13))"
```

Nothing worked.

Comment: Try `echo.|abcd.bat` or even better add `echo.|` to a command which expects Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
```

Sometimes this works where {ENTER} doesn't.  Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing an '**WScript.Shell**', you could use the standard functionality of UFT/QTP:

```
SystemUtil.Run "D:\Path\To\batch.bat"
```

Have an look at the official SystemUtil Reference: [SystemUtil Object](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.51/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#StdWin/STDPACKAGELib~SystemUtil.html#Run)